# YouTubeの見過ぎ対策で

Tags: python, python3, c#, c, youtube

超初学者です
YouTubeの見過ぎ対策で、一定時間YouTubeを開き続けると自動的に落ちるツールを作ることは可能でしょうか
また仮に可能だとしてそれをpythonで実装することはできるでしょうか
ハードはiPhone,mac希望です

プログラミング自体始めたてで、どんなことができるのかよく分かってないため質問させていただきました。
ちなみに今の自分はif文for文などひよこレベルです！

Comment: iPhone だと恐らくアプリで、Mac ではブラウザからアクセスする事になると思いますが、どちらの制御を想定していますか？また、iPhone であればスクリーンタイム等の機能も用意されていますが、あくまで自分でプログラムを作るのが目標ですか？

Comment: 「YouTubeのトラフィックを監視し、一定の時間・容量の通信が行われていたらトラフィックを遮断する（ことで、YouTubeを使えなくする）プロキシ」は作ることが可能です。しかし、 @cubick 氏の指摘通り、標準で搭載されているスクリーンタイム等の機能を利用するほうがはるかに簡単そうです。

Answer (score 2):

iPhone での利用を制限したい場合、自作せずとも、Apple が標準で提供しているペアレンタルコントロールの機能である、スクリーンタイムを設定するのが早いです: https://support.apple.com/ja-jp/guide/iphone/iph7f15d92dd/ios

> ファミリーメンバーのデバイスに休止時間とAppの制限を設定する
>
> 1. ファミリーメンバーのデバイスで、「設定」  ＞「スクリーンタイム」と選択します。
> 2. 「スクリーンタイムをオンにする」＞「続ける」＞「これは子供用のiPhoneです」と選択します。
> 3. ファミリーメンバーの休止時間（画面から離れる時間）を設定するには、開始時刻と終了時刻を入力してから、「休止時間を設定」をタップします。
> 4. ファミリーメンバーのために管理したいAppのカテゴリ（ゲームやSNSなど）に制限を設けるには、そのカテゴリを選択します。
>    すべてのカテゴリを表示するには、「すべてのカテゴリを表示」をタップします。
> 5. 「設定」をタップしてから、時間を入力し、「App使用時間の制限を設定」をタップします。
> 6. 「続ける」をタップしてから、ファミリーメンバーのスクリーンタイム設定を管理するスクリーンタイム用パスコードを入力します。

Answer (score 0):

一定時間で自動的に落ちるようにするってことは、他のアプリを自動的に止めることになります。
これはちょっと難しいかもしれません。
発想を変えて、一定時間で停止する機能を持った、YouTubeのビューアを作成するというのであれば、比較的簡単に作成できると思います。
ただいずれにしましても、ある程度の知識が必要になりますので、まずは普通にアプリの作成方法を勉強するところからすすめた方がいいと思います。
iPhone,Macのアプリはxcodeで作成します。
xcodeは無償でインストールできますので、簡単なプログラムから作ってみましょう。
macのアプリは作ったものを簡単に配布できますが、iPhoneのアプリはいろいろ
面倒なことがありますので、そのあたりも調べた方がいいと思います。
iPhoneのアプリは、自分専用であればあんまり問題ありません。

上記のソフトはpythonでも可能かもしれませんが、ある程度の規模以上のアプリを
作りたい場合は、Swift等の方がいいかもしれません。